# Clien-side validation and server-side validation not working together (on double's)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a product class with a price property:

```cs
[Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

In the root webconfig I have this element:

```xml
<globalization culture="nl-NL" uiCulture="nl-NL" />
```

I use a simple @Html.EditorForModel() method to generate html for me.

Short, if the price of a product is 7 euro and 95 cents the rendered html will display 7,95 and not 7.95. (Note the difference between the dot(.) and the comma(,))

I have an edit controller responsible for saving any product updates to the (ms) db. 
Using only server side validation and no client side validation, if I change the price from 7,95 to 7,96 everything is saved perfectly. If I change the price from 7,95 to 7.96(note to dot!) the new price is €796,00. However, this is fixable by not letting a dot(.) being entered in the text field of the price property.

But now the trouble starts. When I enable client-side validation along side with server-side validation and try to change the value of 7,95 to 7,96 I get an client-side error message stating: "The field Price must be a number." It only accepts numbers with a dot(.) (ie:7.96) and no numbers with a comma(,) (ie:7,96)

**There are probably multiple solutions to this question, but the solution I am looking for is the one where I can somehow configure the "client-side validator" to accept numbers with a comma** (and if possible at the same time can configure to reject numbers with a dot. That way I won't have to use reg-expressions on every property which is a double type)

Comment: Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: Which version of MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MVC 3 or higher, you need to include the "messages" and "methods" locale files for the jQuery validation plugin that MVC uses. You can get them here:

- https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization

  - [messages_nl.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/messages_nl.js)
  - [methods_nl.js](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/methods_nl.js)

Unfortunately, the `methods_nl.js` file lacks a number validator that would match the decimal format you're using. According to the [Decimal mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) Wiki article, in the Netherlands, the format you're using is generally only used for currency. The number validator is probably not overridden because of this, so you may need to add one yourself:

```
$.extend($.validator.methods, {
    date: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?[\.\/\-]\d\d?[\.\/\-]\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    },
    // Add this:
    number: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

To avoid overriding the general number format, you may want to add it as a custom validation method instead (use a different attribute name):

```
$.extend($.validator.methods, {
    date: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?[\.\/\-]\d\d?[\.\/\-]\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    },
    // Add this:
    currency: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

You will then have to build custom validation classes as described in this article:

- http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

In the class derived from `ModelClientValidationRule`, you can specify the validation type as "currency". You will register that subclass to glue it all together.

Good luck!